# How to provide modified data in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a parent component where the initial data is set like this:

```
  export default {
  components: {
    GameBoard,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [
        {id: "penguin", name: "penguin"},
        {id: "tiger", name: "tiger"},
        {id: "monkey", name: "monkey"},
        {id: "lion", name: "lion"},
      ]
    };
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      cards: this.cards
    };
  },
created() {
this.prepareCards();
methods: {
prepareCards() {
  let gameCards = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
    gameCards.push({
        id: this.cards[i].name + 2,
        name: this.cards[i].name + 2,
    });
  }
    this.cards = this.cards.concat(gameCards);

    console.log("gameCards: " + JSON.stringify(this.cards));
},
```

Then I create a new array (gameCards) and add the array with concat to the data array.

But when I loop over the array in the template it only consist of the previous data array with 4 objects.

```
 <CardResource
    v-for="card in cards"
    :key="card.id"
    :id="card.id"
    :name="card.name"
  ></CardResource>
```

The console.log told me that there are 8 objects in the array.
It looks like the provide() method does not know about the modified cards array. How to let it know it?

Comment: when is prepareCards being called? Is it called after or before CardResource is instantiated?

Comment: In created(). There is one closing bracket missing. I edited it, but it was not possible to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work as expected when I put it in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const App = {
    data() {
      return {
        cards: [
          {id: "penguin", name: "penguin"},
          {id: "tiger", name: "tiger"},
          {id: "monkey", name: "monkey"},
          {id: "lion", name: "lion"},
        ]
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.prepareCards();
    },
    methods: {
      prepareCards() {
        let gameCards = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
          gameCards.push({
            id: this.cards[i].name + 2,
            name: this.cards[i].name + 2,
          });
        }
        this.cards = this.cards.concat(gameCards);

        console.log("gameCards: " + JSON.stringify(this.cards));
      }
    }
  }
      const app = createApp(App)
      app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <div
    v-for="card in cards"
    :key="card.id"
  >{{ card }}</div>


</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: In a single component that could be the case.
I am using two more components, GameBoard and CardResource. Probably the values are not passed the child components.

Comment: Please update your question with enough details so your problem can be understood and answered